# iTunes Album Rating for ALL songs on album, not just rated songs

Tags: itunes

Is there any way to tell iTunes to calculate the Album Rating for an album as the average rating for *all* songs on an album instead of the average rating of songs that have a rating?

Answer (score 1):

It is already factoring those in: they just have a NULL rating.

NULL is not 0 - it's a lack of rating.

If you want the unrated songs to be rated 0, you need to do that yourself.